# Simplest possible Paxos algorithm (distributed consensus) explanation

Tags: networks, p2p

I am looking for a simple explanation of the **[Paxos algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_%28computer_science%29)** that can be used for reaching consensus in a distributed environment (possibly peer to peer network).

Every explanation I have encountered so far was a tough reading of multiple pages. I am looking for a simplified explanation that still preserves the core principles.

Comment: What _exactly_ is confusing you?

Comment: I am a total newbie to this field... every explanation I have encountered so far was a tough reading of multiple pages. Looking for a rather simplified explanation that still preserves the core principles.

Comment: That depends on what you would include under "core principles". Oleksi's answer could suffice, or not. Does it?

Answer (score 7):

I've found [this explanation](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0) in the context of Cassandra lightweight transactions useful.

> Prepare/promise is the core of the algorithm. Any node may propose a value; we call that node the leader. (Note that many nodes may attempt to act as leaders simultaneously! This is not a “master” role.) The leader picks a ballot and sends it to the participating replicas. If the ballot is the highest a replica has seen, it promises to not accept any proposals associated with any earlier ballot. Along with that promise, it includes the most recent proposal it has already received.
>
> If a majority of the nodes promise to accept the leader’s proposal, it
>   may proceed to the actual proposal, but with the wrinkle that if a
>   majority of replicas included an earlier proposal with their promise,
>   then that is the value the leader must propose. Conceptually, if a
>   leader interrupts an earlier leader, it must first finish that
>   leader’s proposal before proceeding with its own, thus giving us our
>   desired linearizable behavior.

[image: Paxos in Cassandra]

References

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0